# Laravel 7 eloquent join with relavent record of right table

Tags: mysql, join, eloquent, laravel-7

I am fetching product price after applying catalog rules on products, I build a sql query and trying to do this query in Laravel 7 with Eloquent but unable to get relavent record from catalog_rule join because catalog_rule may has multiple records for a product and i must to pick most relavent and recent record including override ='yes'.

SQL Query:

```
            SELECT    products.*, hike_rule.hike_type, hike_rule.hike_amount, discount_rule.hike_amount as discount
            IF(hike_rule.hike_amount > 0, 
                IF(hike_rule.hike_type = 'percent'),
                    @product_price := (products.price + products.price*hike_rule.hike_amount/100)
                    ,
                    @product_price := (products.price + hike_rule.hike_amount)
            ,
            @product_price := products.price) as product_price,
            IF(discount > 0,
                @product_sale_price := (@product_price + @product_price*discount/100)
                ,
                @product_sale_price := @product_price
            ) as product_sale_price

            FROM      products 
            LEFT JOIN      (
                        SELECT    *  FROM   catalog_rule_products,catalog_rule where  catalog_rule_products.rule_id = catalog_rule.rule_id and catalog_rule.status = 'active' and (catalog_rule.from_date != "0000-00-00" and catalog_rule.from_date <= NOW() ) and (catalog_rule.to_date != "0000-00-00" and catalog_rule.to_date >= NOW() ) and catalog_rule.rule_type = 'price_hike'
                        order by IF(override ='yes', 1, 0),rule_id desc 
                    ) hike_rule ON (hike_rule.product_id = products.product_id)
           LEFT JOIN      (
                        SELECT    * 
                        FROM      catalog_rule_products,catalog_rule
                        where  catalog_rule_products.rule_id = catalog_rule.rule_id and catalog_rule.status = 'active' and (catalog_rule.from_date != "0000-00-00" and catalog_rule.from_date <= NOW() ) and (catalog_rule.to_date != "0000-00-00" and catalog_rule.to_date >= NOW() ) and catalog_rule.rule_type = 'price_discount'  order by IF(override ='yes', 1, 0),rule_id desc 
                    ) discount_rule ON (discount_rule.product_id = products.product_id)

            WHERE     products.category_id = 3 group by products.product_id
            order by product_sale_price desc
```

I have pagination, searching, sorting  too with products and other are working.

Table structure:

1. products

   product_id , sku, category_id, qty, price
2. catalog_rule

   ```
    CREATE TABLE `catalog_rule` (

     `rule_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
     `name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
     `rule_type` enum('price_discount','price_hike') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'price_discount',
      `description` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `from_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
      `to_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
      `is_active` enum('enabled','disabled') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'disabled',
      `conditions_type` enum('category','price','sku') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `sku` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `category_slug` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `sort_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
      `hike_amount` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
      `hike_type` enum('percent','fixed') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'percent',
      `country_code` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `override` enum('yes','no') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
      `skip_products` enum('yes','no') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no'
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

   INSERT INTO `catalog_rule` (`rule_id`, `name`, `rule_type`, `description`, `from_date`, `to_date`, `is_active`, `conditions_type`, `sku`, `category_slug`, `sort_order`, `hike_amount`, `hike_type`, `country_code`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `override`, `skip_products`) VALUES
      (3, 'new rule', 'price_discount', 'test', '2021-10-07', '2022-01-31', 'enabled', 'category', '', 'gowns', 0, '15.00', 'percent', 'all', '2021-10-06 07:29:43', '2022-01-31 08:52:49', 'no', 'no'),
      (4, 'test2 rule', 'price_hike', NULL, '2021-12-01', '2022-01-31', 'enabled', 'category', '', 'gowns', 0, '70.00', 'percent', 'all', '2022-01-31 08:49:20', '2022-01-31 08:52:03', 'no', 'no'),
       (5, 'test2 rule hike jutti', 'price_hike', NULL, '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00', 'enabled', 'category', 'a:4:{i:0;s:12:\"MBAG2110AV20\";i:1;s:12:\"MBAG2112CMR6\";i:2;s:11:\"MFM2006MCA2\";i:3;s:19:\"MLADIES-JUT2108BAW5\";}', 'ladies-juttis', 0, '30.00', 'percent', 'all', '2022-03-04 12:53:02', '2022-03-08 11:10:17', 'no', 'yes'),
       (6, 'shoes products hike', 'price_hike', NULL, '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00', 'enabled', 'sku', 'a:2:{i:0;s:19:\"MLADIES-JUT2108AV0J\";i:1;s:19:\"MLADIES-JUT2108AV26\";}', NULL, 0, '40.00', 'percent', 'all', '2022-03-08 11:12:48', '2022-03-08 11:12:48', 'no', 'no'),
       (7, 'shoes products1', 'price_hike', NULL, '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00', 'enabled', 'sku', 'a:1:{i:0;s:19:\"MLADIES-JUT2108BAW5\";}', NULL, 0, '35.00', 'percent', 'all', '2022-03-08 11:15:00', '2022-03-08 11:41:39', 'no', 'no'),
       (8, 'hand bags 25% hike', 'price_hike', NULL, '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00', 'enabled', 'category', '', 'ladies-bags', 0, '25.00', 'percent', 'all', '2022-03-08 11:15:54', '2022-03-12 02:12:52', 'no', 'no'),
        (9, 'saree 30% hike', 'price_hike', NULL, '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00', 'disabled', 'category', '', 'sarees', 0, '30.00', 'percent', 'all', '2022-03-08 11:44:51', '2022-03-11 05:06:08', 'no', 'no'),
        ( 10, 'Saree 40% hike', 'price_hike', NULL, '2022-03-04', '2022-03-11', 'disabled', 'category', '', 'sarees', 0, '40.00', 'percent', 'all', '2022-03-08 14:21:09', '2022-03-11 05:05:41', 'no', 'no'),
        (11, 'hike 25% on sarees', 'price_hike', NULL, '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00', 'enabled', 'category', '', 'sarees', 0, '25.00', 'percent', 'all', '2022-03-09 04:29:00', '2022-03-11 06:12:35', 'yes', 'no'),
         (12, 'discount 30% saree', 'price_discount', NULL, '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00', 'disabled', 'category', '', 'sarees', 0, '30.00', 'fixed', 'all', '2022-03-09 06:03:26', '2022-03-11 05:06:49', 'no', 'no'),
        (13, 'discount 40% saree', 'price_discount', NULL, '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00', 'disabled', 'category', '', 'sarees', 0, '40.00', 'percent', 'all', '2022-03-09 10:02:30', '2022-03-09 10:02:30', 'yes', 'no'),
       (14, 'shirts 10% discount', 'price_discount', NULL, '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00', 'enabled', 'category', '', 'shirts', 0, '10.00', 'percent', 'all', '2022-03-10 08:48:42', '2022-03-11 12:01:48', 'no', 'no');
   ```
3. Catalog_rule_products

   ```
    CREATE TABLE `catalog_rule_products` (
      `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `rule_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `product_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
   ```

   INSERT INTO `catalog_rule_products` (`id`, `rule_id`, `product_id`) VALUES
   (2, 7, 2160),
   (1045, 13, 176),
   (1046, 13, 178),
   (1047, 13, 179),
   (1048, 13, 230),
   (1049, 13, 231),
   (1050, 13, 232),
   (1051, 13, 233),
   (1052, 13, 234),
   (1053, 13, 235),
   (1054, 13, 236),
   (1055, 13, 237),
   (1056, 13, 238),
   (1057, 13, 239),
   (1058, 13, 240),
   (1059, 13, 241),
   (1060, 13, 242),
   (1061, 13, 243),
   (1062, 13, 244),
   (1063, 13, 245),
   (1064, 13, 246),
   (1065, 13, 247),
   (1066, 13, 248),
   (1067, 13, 249),
   (1068, 13, 250),
   (1069, 13, 251),
   (1070, 13, 252),
   (1071, 13, 253),
   (1072, 13, 254),
   (1073, 13, 255),
   (1074, 13, 256),
   (1075, 13, 257),
   (1076, 13, 258),
   (1077, 13, 259),
   (1078, 13, 260),
   (1079, 13, 261),
   (1080, 13, 262),
   (1081, 13, 263),
   (1082, 13, 264),
   (1083, 13, 265),
   (1084, 13, 266),
   (1085, 13, 267),
   (1086, 13, 268),
   (1087, 13, 269),
   (1088, 13, 270),
   (1089, 13, 271),
   (1090, 13, 272),
   (1091, 13, 273),
   (1092, 13, 274),
   (1093, 13, 275),
   (1094, 13, 276),
   (1095, 13, 277),
   (1096, 13, 278),
   (1097, 13, 279),
   (1098, 13, 280),
   (1099, 13, 281),
   (1100, 13, 282),
   (1101, 13, 283),
   (1102, 13, 284),
   (1103, 13, 285),
   (1104, 13, 286),
   (1105, 13, 287),
   (1106, 13, 288),
   (1107, 13, 290),
   (1108, 13, 291),
   (1109, 13, 292),
   (1110, 13, 294),
   (1111, 13, 295),
   (1112, 13, 305),
   (1113, 13, 307),
   (1114, 13, 308),
   (1115, 13, 309),
   (1116, 13, 310),
   (1117, 13, 311),
   (1118, 13, 312),
   (1119, 13, 313),
   (1120, 13, 314),
   (1121, 13, 316),
   (1122, 13, 318),
   (1123, 13, 320),
   (1124, 13, 322),
   (1125, 13, 323),
   (1126, 13, 325),
   (1127, 13, 326),
   (1128, 13, 327),
   (1129, 13, 334),
   (1130, 13, 457),
   (1131, 13, 458),
   (1132, 13, 459),
   (1133, 13, 460),
   (1134, 13, 461),
   (1135, 13, 462),
   (1136, 13, 463),
   (1137, 13, 464),
   (1138, 13, 465),
   (1139, 13, 468),
   (1140, 13, 469),
   (1141, 13, 472),
   (1142, 13, 474),
   (1143, 13, 475),
   (1144, 13, 480),
   (1145, 13, 482),
   (1146, 13, 484),
   (1147, 13, 485),
   (1148, 13, 2135),
   (1149, 13, 2135),
   (1150, 13, 2135),
   (1151, 13, 2135),
   (1152, 13, 2136),
   (1153, 13, 2137),
   (1154, 13, 2138),
   (1155, 13, 2144),
   (1156, 13, 2148),
   (1157, 13, 2151),
   (1158, 13, 2170),
   (1159, 13, 2170),
   (1160, 13, 2174),
   (1972, 11, 176),
   (1973, 11, 178),
   (1974, 11, 179),
   (1975, 11, 230),
   (1976, 11, 231),
   (1977, 11, 232),
   (1978, 11, 233),
   (1979, 11, 234),
   (1980, 11, 235),
   (1981, 11, 236),
   (1982, 11, 237),
   (1983, 11, 238),
   (1984, 11, 239),
   (1985, 11, 240),
   (1986, 11, 241),
   (1987, 11, 242),
   (1988, 11, 243),
   (1989, 11, 244),
   (1990, 11, 245),
   (1991, 11, 246),
   (1992, 11, 247),
   (1993, 11, 248),
   (1994, 11, 249),
   (1995, 11, 250),
   (1996, 11, 251),
   (1997, 11, 252),
   (1998, 11, 253),
   (1999, 11, 254),
   (2000, 11, 255),
   (2001, 11, 256),
   (2002, 11, 257),
   (2003, 11, 258),
   (2004, 11, 259),
   (2005, 11, 260),
   (2006, 11, 261),
   (2007, 11, 262),
   (2008, 11, 263),
   (2009, 11, 264),
   (2010, 11, 265),
   (2011, 11, 266),
   (2012, 11, 267),
   (2013, 11, 268),
   (2014, 11, 269),
   (2015, 11, 270),
   (2016, 11, 271),
   (2017, 11, 272),
   (2018, 11, 273),
   (2019, 11, 274),
   (2020, 11, 275),
   (2021, 11, 276),
   (2022, 11, 277),
   (2023, 11, 278),
   (2024, 11, 279),
   (2025, 11, 280),
   (2026, 11, 281),
   (2027, 11, 282),
   (2028, 11, 283),
   (2029, 11, 284),
   (2030, 11, 285),
   (2031, 11, 286),
   (2032, 11, 287),
   (2033, 11, 288),
   (2034, 11, 290),
   (2035, 11, 291),
   (2036, 11, 292),
   (2037, 11, 294),
   (2038, 11, 295),
   (2039, 11, 305),
   (2040, 11, 307),
   (2041, 11, 308),
   (2042, 11, 309),
   (2043, 11, 310),
   (2044, 11, 311),
   (2045, 11, 312),
   (2046, 11, 313),
   (2047, 11, 314),
   (2048, 11, 316),
   (2049, 11, 318),
   (2050, 11, 320),
   (2051, 11, 322),
   (2052, 11, 323),
   (2053, 11, 325),
   (2054, 11, 326),
   (2055, 11, 327),
   (2056, 11, 334),
   (2057, 11, 457),
   (2058, 11, 458),
   (2059, 11, 459),
   (2060, 11, 460),
   (2061, 11, 461),
   (2062, 11, 462),
   (2063, 11, 463),
   (2064, 11, 464),
   (2065, 11, 465),
   (2066, 11, 468),
   (2067, 11, 469),
   (2068, 11, 472),
   (2069, 11, 474),
   (2070, 11, 475),
   (2071, 11, 480),
   (2072, 11, 482),
   (2073, 11, 484),
   (2074, 11, 485),
   (2075, 11, 2135),
   (2076, 11, 2135),
   (2077, 11, 2135),
   (2078, 11, 2135),
   (2079, 11, 2136),
   (2080, 11, 2137),
   (2081, 11, 2138),
   (2082, 11, 2144),
   (2083, 11, 2148),
   (2084, 11, 2151),
   (2085, 11, 2170),
   (2086, 11, 2170),
   (2087, 11, 2174),
   (2089, 14, 2176),
   (2090, 8, 2173),
   (2091, 8, 2181),
   (2092, 8, 2182),
   (2093, 8, 2183),
   (2094, 8, 2187);

Comment: Can you provide your table definitions and some sample data?

Comment: @Kendle I have edited question with table definitions and some sample data.